# Determine whether constraint name is system generated in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, constraints, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to find if a constraint name is 'system generated' or 'manually given at the time of creation'.

MS SQL Server has a column 'is_system_named' in `sys.key_constraints`:

1 = Name was generated by system.
0 = Name was supplied by the user.

I tried to find similar in `information_schema.table_constraints`. Could not find it.

Use case is basically while migrating the databases, if manually named constraints are present then it will be easy to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing of the sort in the relevant system catalog [`pg_constraint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-constraint.html).

You can check the default naming pattern and if you see a different name, you can be sure it has been named explicitly. Other than that, I don't think you can tell for sure.